# How to get Accounts.createUser() Info in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I did a sample registration application using  **Accounts.createUser()** in `Meteor`. After registration  tried to get all values based on email but not get it.I didn't have any idea.So please see the below code and suggest me what to do.

```
Accounts.createUser({email: email, password : password,username : uname,profile : {firstname : fname,middlename : mname,lastname:lname,country : country,zip : zip,desc : desc} }, function(err)
                {
                   if (err) 
                    {
                      console.log(err);
                      alert(err.reason);
                    }
                    else
                    {


                  console.log("Register Successfully");

                    //Here trying to get details

                  console.log(Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.address": email}));
                }
            });
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

After registration, the user is saved in `Meteor.users` collection. So, you can get user info with that :

```
Meteor.users.findOne({'emails.address': {$regex:text,$options:'i'}});
```

You have also `Accounts.onCreateUser(func)`, called whenever a new user is created. **Return the new user object**, or throw an Error to abort the creation.

[documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser)

Comment: Not working ..i am using as you told above ,But i get "undefined". So what i can do for this problem?.@EpokK.

Comment: Hum ... Maybe you have a config problem with Meteor.

Comment: there may be two problems here. 1) emails in the users document is an array. 2) emails are not published to client by default